# How to check if a Domino database exists before opening it?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I have an application that reads quite a few domino databases. These databases are split between a main database, and some cabinets (or sub-databases) linked to the main database.

But those databases don't have the same number of cabinets attached to them. It goes from 1 to 15.
As I need to read all of them (93 databases currently), I used to list all of the paths to the nsf files and read them one by one. However, the number of cabinets can change with time, meaning that I need to regularly check if I need to add new files. And I don't want to do that...
So I figured another way: I list only a template of the names of nsf files (all the cabinets are named like `database00.nsf, database01.nsf, etc`, so it's easy to generate those file names at runtime, and when I try to open a database and get an COMException, I assume that the database doesn't exist, and remove it from my list.
BUT! This is awfully slow and definitely not a good practice!

This is what I currently have. `_listDBs` holds a list of the paths to the databases' nsf file, and `tmplist` is temporary list, used later to clean `_listDbs`

```cs
foreach (var pair in _listDBs)
{
    try
    {
        NotesDatabase notedb = _notesSession.GetDatabase(_lotusRoot, pair.Value);
        //other stuff here, not important
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        tmplist.Add(pair);
    }
}
```

I have to wait for the COMException to be raised to identify that the database doesn't exist.
I would prefer to check first if the nsf file exists. But I can't find a way to do that. I couldn't find a way to navigate the Domino server differently.
Any leads?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 100% way to determine if a database exists without trying to open it. you could go through the documents in catalog.nsf and check if there is one for your path, but this database is updated only nightly and might be out of date at the time you check it.

BUT: you can go the other way around: use a NotesDbDirectory, loop through it and check the filepath of the databases if they match your list.

The NotesDbDicrectory contains all databases on the server and looping through it is very fast.

As I am not familiar with c#, here a COM Example for Visual Basic taken from Designer help

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
s.Initialize
Dim dir As NotesDbDirectory
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set dir = s.GetDbDirectory("Snapper")
Set db = dir.GetFirstDatabase(NOTES_DATABASE)
While Not (db Is Nothing)
  ˋCheck db.Filename or db.Filepath here
  Set db = dir.GetNextDatabase
Wend
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. I tried to play with GetDbDirectory but could not find how to get the correct data from there.